# Android open server to send datas over inner network, to my PC (over WIFI)

Tags: android

I have an android phone, i d like to send some stream's, to my computer. (192.168.1....:8080)

What is the best way of it?

So i d like to run a test:

- i'd like to "look" all my windows files on my phone,
- i'd like to send maybe a camera stream to my browser, or other program.

What is the way to do it? Is it hard?

Thanks, 
Leslie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it:

http://code.google.com/p/android-simple-httpserver-camerapicture/

Answer (score 0):

In order to see all your Windows files on your phone, you have to either share your entire hard drive(s) in Windows and use an SMB client on your phone, which would be a major security hole. Alternatively, you could write a server program that could do it, which is also a security hole if discovered unless you use some really good encryption. To send a camera stream requires a large amount of bandwidth and processing power; I've seen it attempted before, but it's always really choppy and not usable. In short, the first part is possible and difficult, and the second is mostly impossible.